# Why UIWebView loads HTML with embed frames so long?

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I load my HTML via UIWebView with:

```
let baseURL = "<html>...</html>"
self.webView.loadHTMLString("\(baseURL)<h3><b>\(self.post.first!.title)</b></h3>\(dateHTML)\((self.post.first?.content)!)\(closures)", baseURL: nil)
```

these 2 lines. In general everything is okay, but when I have on my HTML pages YouTube video frames it does not open the page. It loads, loads and loads the page continuously.

How can I prevent that?

If exactly, I have a loader, and I remove it in:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webVieww: UIWebView) {
    self.loaderView?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

so my loader does not disappear if I have YouTube videos embedded in my HTML. How can I fix and prevent that?